# Java + Advantage Database Server -> Login failed

Tags: java, advantage-database-server

this java app was working fine for years. It reads the data from an Advantage Database Server an accounting software uses. Since a recent update of that accounting software, all I get is a "Login failed" exception. As far as my knowledge goes, there's no way to "login" or use credentials to login to an Advantage Database Server..

```
address = "//localhost:6262";
catalog = "D:\bob50\DATA\DEMO";

Class.forName("com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver");
this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage:"+address+";catalog="+catalog+";TableType=adt;LockType=proprietary;LockType=compatible;");
```

Does anyone know why "Login failed" would be triggered? The Advantage Database Server is running..

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to "login" to an Advantage Database Server if you are connecting to a Data Dictionary (file.add).  In your case, though you are correct that the error message is misleading as the connection is to a folder (Free table connection).

The first thing I would try is use your actual hostname or actual IP address rather than localhost.  And the second is I would recommend using all forward slashes.

If that fails, open the error log on the server with ARC and check for errors around the time you tried your connection.  I've seen where the login failure error (7078) can be returned for an invalid path.